# Can we modify ORM Doctrine Framework?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project's source code, there are some classes having some methods and variables that are auto-generated by **Doctrine ORM Framework**, whose definition are difficult to find.

Is anyone having any idea of how to find the body definitions of the methods provided by ORM Doctrine Framework ?

Regards,
Megha

Comment: What methods for example? - The documentation is quite big and I think everything is in there. https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: It's not that difficult if you're using proper IDE ;)

Comment: Your question is a bit deceptive: title asks if you can, question already knows you can and asks where

Comment: Scenario is : I have downloaded the open source code of a HR portal. That code uses ORM framework which has some pre-defined methods like getContactNumber(), setConatctNumber(), and hundreds of methods like these. I need to add some more methods for which I need to get the body definitions of the mentioned methods first. @Xatenev

Comment: Either I failed to explain it correctly or u got it wrong. I am a beginner to work with ORM Framework, so I am not sure about whether we can add methods in ORM or not. But I tried to do so and didn't get any way. That's why title asks whether we can modify ORM Framework or not. Sorry if my question decepted you. :( @DamienPirsy

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify vendor code.

You can look at the Doctrine code that's installed in your Symfony2 project by looking in the vendor/doctrine folder.

If you make modifications to the code there, if you update your application, or want to install it anywhere else, your modifications will not be saved. Therefore rendering them useless.

Comment: Thanks for your attention :) . But if I should not modify vendor code, then do you have any idea what should I do in order to edit my application ??

Comment: Most libraries, like Doctrine, provide interfaces for you to create your own versions of things. Or, allow you to extend built-in classes.  Which methods in particular are you have problems with?

Comment: Scenario is : I have downloaded the open source code of a HR portal. That code uses Doctrine ORM and Symfony framework which auto generates methods like getContactNumber(), setConatctNumber(), and hundreds of methods like these. I need to add some more methods for which I need to get the body definitions of the mentioned methods first. I followed the documentations of Doctrine and Symfony, but didnt get any effective way. I am not getting those files in my project code which those documentations are telling me to edit.

Comment: Okay, well from the names of those methods they sound more like Entity methods. There should be an entity class, let's say we're talking about the details of a 'Person' here, there should be a `Person` class that's associated with the database table. See if you have any luck finding an Entity.

Comment: I used the code browser to find the definitions of those methods...but didn't get them unluckily. :( These methods are autogenerated. No definitions all over the source code.

Comment: Did you try to look for Entities?

Comment: ya got the entity class which is describing about the database table. :)

Comment: http://wiki.orangehrm.com/index.php/Developing_With_Symfony#Database_access :         This is the page describing to add custom fields in the database.... as per this page, I first edited the schema.yml page(containing the entity class), then ran this command:"  php symfony doctrine:build-schema  "..... but still the methods are not autogenerated. :(

Comment: Can you add them yourself?

Comment: No, that is the thing which i am not getting: "how to auto generate the methods ". :(

Comment: I'd consider modifying your question to clarify that, and anything else you feel is necessary that we've discussed. What's stopping you from adding them yourself?

Comment: The schema.yml files represent the existing strucuture of the database. As per the wiki page of orangehrm, we need to first edit the schema.yml file and dbscript files(like adding new methods), then we are instructed to run this command: " php symfony doctrine:build-schema ".As per them, this command will generate a new schema file representing the edited structure of the database and it will also autogenerate the newly added methods, but nothing like that happened.

Comment: I think your docs might not be talking about the right version of Symfony. Try this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html, and then this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters

Comment: I read this document earlier...but this didn't work... No problem.... I'll again explore it and will then update you.....by the way thanks for coordinating me this much..... :)

Comment: After following the orangehrm wiki page, I am now able to autogenerate the schema.yml file(on running the command : "php symfony doctrine:build-schema" ) which is representing the structure of the existing database. But when I add more entities to the schema.yml file and run the same command, though its again autogenerated but doesn't contain the newly added entities, which in turn indicates that the newly added entities are not added to the db.

Comment: And one more thing, the process which doctrine and symfony wiki page is describing to add entities in the db is completely different from the method described by orangehrm wiki. :( So basically my current concern is to get the input files for schema.yml.(i.e, in which files do we need to add the custom entities in order to get them in autogenerated schema.yml file).

Comment: I wish I knew anything about OrangeHRM. :/ at least if you're closer to solving this you could open a new, more specific question about this? "Where do I add entries to in order to auto-generate entities in OrangeHRM?" or something?

Comment: Is there something else wrong? You've unmarked this question as answered.

Comment: yes..... i failed to continue in this way. I got another way to solve my question. :)